# What is the reason and resolution for package uses old Order Save Behavior?

Tags: package-install, release, critical-update, install

My client asked why certain subscribers of the package I build on behalf of my client, cannot install the package.

When they try to install the package, the following error appears

> Can't install the package. This package uses old Order Save Behavior
> and can't be part of orgs that use new Order Save Behavior. For more
> information, review the Winter '21 Order Save Behavior documentation,
> or contact the package's developer.

Our package doesn't use Order Save behavior and such error message is confusing and misleading.

What is the reason for such an error and what is the possible resolution for this?

Answer (score 1):

There is [new release update](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_order_save_behavior.htm) about order save behavior which impacts installation of any package which do not even depend on the Order Save behavior.

To mitigate this problem, create a new configuration file `OSBB.json`

```
{
    "orgName": "OSBB",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "features": ["OrderSaveBehaviorBoth"],
    "settings": {
    }
}
```

and update the `sfdx-project.json` to include `"definitionFile": "config/OSBB.json",`

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "package": "Baseline",
            "versionName": "0.0.0",
            "versionNumber": "0.0.0.NEXT",
            "definitionFile": "config/OSBB.json",
            "default": true
        }
    ],
```

Another possible option which doesn't include the package release is the following. Subscribers can click "Disable test run" button in Salesforce Setup / Release updates and then install the package and then click the button "Enable test run" again

Some other option is to contact Salesforce support and request explanation why package install fails for a package which is Order agnostic.

[There was some known issue about installation of some packages in Winter21 but it is closed now](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?Id=a1p4V0000003weE)